Regex for (x,y) and (x,y] in R
i'm using R, and i have a df with a column that has bins that follow one of these two formats:
(x.xx,y.yy] or (x.xx,y.yy)

they are all positive integers with multiple decimals
i want to split them into
lower upper
x.xx  y.yy

i first filter all all NAs out of the bin column (there are a few across multiple dfs):
filter(!is.na(bin))

i'm currently using this regex:
mutate(
lower = as.numeric(sub("^[\\(\\[]([0-9.-]+),", "\\1", bin))  
upper = as.numeric(sub(",([0-9.-]+)[\\)\\]]$", "\\1", bin))
)

but it produces all NAs
I haven't tried many alternatives, any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance
here is a test data example:
> test_bins <- c("[0.15,0.273]", "(0.273,0.397]", "(0.397,0.52]", "[0.52,0.643]")

> lower_values <- sapply(test_bins, function(x) as.numeric(sub("^[\\[\\(]([0-9.]+),", "\\1", x)))
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

> upper_values <- sapply(test_bins, function(x) as.numeric(sub(",([0-9.]+)[\\)\\]]$", "\\1", x)))
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

> data.frame(test_bins, lower_values, upper_values)
                  test_bins lower_values upper_values
[0.15,0.273]   [0.15,0.273]           NA           NA
(0.273,0.397] (0.273,0.397]           NA           NA
(0.397,0.52]   (0.397,0.52]           NA           NA
[0.52,0.643]   [0.52,0.643]           NA           NA


The first one must be ^[([]([0-9.-]+),.*. The second one must be .*,([0-9.-]+)[])]$. See the R demo online.

this works, thank you so much!

another one read.csv(text = c('lower,upper', gsub('[][()]', '', test_bins)))

1) Read the input into a data frame and apply parse_number to each column. No regular expressions are used.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

test_bins %>%
  bind_cols(input = ., {
    read.table(text = ., sep = ",", col.names = c("lower", "upper")) %>%
    map_dfr(parse_number)
  })

giving
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  input         lower upper
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 [0.15,0.273]  0.15  0.273
2 (0.273,0.397] 0.273 0.397
3 (0.397,0.52]  0.397 0.52 
4 [0.52,0.643]  0.52  0.643

2) or with only base R where the only regular expression used is \D
test_bins |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with(cbind(input = x, x |>
    read.table(text = _, sep = ",", col.names = c("lower", "upper"))  |>
    lapply(\(x) as.numeric(trimws(x, whitespace = "\\D"))) |>
    data.frame()
))

giving
          input lower upper
1  [0.15,0.273] 0.150 0.273
2 (0.273,0.397] 0.273 0.397
3  (0.397,0.52] 0.397 0.520
4  [0.52,0.643] 0.520 0.643


I suspect you got this from OpenAI GPT model: I tried to ask the same question, and the LLM gave a very similar wrong answer. It gave the right answer only after I told it that R sub uses the TRE regex library by default.
The problem is that you are using a sub function with no perl=TRUE argument, which means the pattern is processed with the default TRE regex engine. In TRE patterns, inside bracket expressions, special characters cannot be escaped. Instead, you need to use "smart placing".
Besides, you only match a part of the input string, and everything that is not matched, remains in the resulting string. To "extract" a value with a sub, you MUST match the whole string, so just add .* in both expressions.
If you want to use your own regexps, you need to re-vamp them as follows: ^[([]([0-9.-]+),.* to detect the "lower" values, and .*,([0-9.-]+)[])]$ to define the upper values.
test_bins <- c("[0.15,0.273]", "(0.273,0.397]", "(0.397,0.52]", "[0.52,0.643]")
lower_values <- as.numeric(sub("^[[(]([0-9.]+),.*", "\\1", test_bins))
upper_values <- as.numeric(sub(".*,([0-9.-]+)[])]$", "\\1", test_bins))
data.frame(test_bins, lower_values, upper_values)
#      test_bins lower_values upper_values
# 1  [0.15,0.273]        0.150        0.273
# 2 (0.273,0.397]        0.273        0.397
# 3  (0.397,0.52]        0.397        0.520
# 4  [0.52,0.643]        0.520        0.643

Here, [[(] matches a [ or ( (the [ must not to be escaped inside a bracket expression) and [])] matches a ] or ) (when the ] is placed right after the open [, it is parsed as a literal ] char).
Here is another solution, a bit simpler: it strips off the round and square brackets on both ends of a string, and splits with a comma:
> strsplit(trimws(test_bins, whitespace="[][()]"), ",")
[[1]]
[1] "0.15"  "0.273"

[[2]]
[1] "0.273" "0.397"

[[3]]
[1] "0.397" "0.52" 

[[4]]
[1] "0.52"  "0.643"

